# How do I assign a string to a variable?

Tags: python, string

I need to assign a string to a variable, but I can not figure out how.
Here is my code:

```
    s_optChoice = input(print("Enter your choice (Rock, Paper or Scizzors: "))
```

When I run this, I get

> Enter your choice (Rock, Paper or Scizzors: None

After None, I can write my option choice, but I don't like that fact that None is printed, how can I get around this?

Comment: You do not need `print` in `input` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you ask for input. Remove `print`.

```
s_optChoice = input("Enter your choice (Rock, Paper or Scizzors: ")
```

Comment: Yes I Just realised this, thank you

Comment: @A.Taylor-Phillips Mark as the answer if this helped.

Comment: I have to wait a minute